# Duplicating an entire Django project

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to duplicate an entire Django project and rename it?

For example, let's say Client1 asks me for a Django project. I would name the entire project Client1. Client2 now comes and asks for the exact same file. Can I simply copy and paste Client1's project and rename it to Client2, or do I need to rename a few other things?

Thank you in advance for the clarification!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properly written django project will work from any directory.  The only thing you need to change is the database settings and, may be, some paths in **settings.py**.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily just copy and paste the Root project folder and name it whatever you wish (here, in case which is Client2). The main changes you have to do is in inner project folder, just go through each file like settings.py,wsgi.py and all of them in it and replace Client1 to Client2. you can easily do it with Find and Replace feature. Dont forget to make the changes in manage.py file. Once you're done, you're good to go to clone your project.